# rocket::response::stream::Event::json() not working

Tags: api, rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, rust-rocket

I am new to rust and I am facing one issue with Event::json().

Following is my code:

```
#[macro_use] 
extern crate rocket;

use rocket::{tokio::sync::broadcast::{channel, Sender, error:: RecvError}, serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}, State, response::stream::{EventStream, Event}, Shutdown};
use rocket::form::Form;
use rocket::tokio::select;


#[derive(Debug, Clone, FromForm, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
struct Message{
    #[field(validate = len(..30))]
    pub room : String,
    #[field(validate = len(..20))]
    pub username : String,
    pub message : String,
}

#[post("/message", data = "<form>")]
fn post(form: Form<Message>, queue : &State<Sender<Message>>) {
    let _res = queue.send(form.into_inner());
}

#[get("/events")]
async fn events(queue: &State<Sender<Message>>, mut end: Shutdown) -> EventStream![] {

let mut rx = queue.subscribe();

EventStream! {
    loop
    {
        let msg = select! {
            msg = rx.recv() => match msg {
                Ok(msg) => msg,
                Err(RecvError::Closed) => break,
                Err(RecvError::Lagged(_)) => continue,
            },
            _ = &mut end => break,

        };

        yield Event::json(&msg);
    }

}
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
    .manage(channel::<Message>(1024).0)
    .mount("/", routes![post, events])
}
```

I am getting error saying,
function or associated item not found in 'Event' at the line : yeild Event::json(&msg);

Detailed Error:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `json` found for struct `Event` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:42:22
   |
42 |         yield Event::json(&msg);
   |                      ^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Event`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `new` due to previous error
```

Help would be appreciated.

I tried importing Event separate line, but it did not work.

I also Ctrl + clicked the Event and went inside the documentation,

json() funtion is available but still it is showing the error.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75443721/edit) your question to include the full error message from `cargo check` (not from an IDE). Rust error messages contain a lot of useful information that IDEs tend to hide.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/response/stream/struct.Event.html#method.json), the `json` method is only available if you enabled the `json` feature. Have you?

Comment: @Jmb I have updated with detail error msg

Comment: @Jmb can you let me know how to enable json please. I am not aware about it. I have dependencies added:

rocket = { version = "0.4.11", features = ["full"]}
reqwest = { version = "0.11.13" , features=["json"]}
lru_time_cache = "0.11.11"
cargo-watch = "8.3.0"

Please let me know.

Comment: Note that the `json` feature is only available for rocket version 0.5, not version 0.4.11. Also there is no feature named `full` in [either](https://docs.rs/crate/rocket/0.4.11/features) [version](https://docs.rs/crate/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/features).

Comment: @Jmb issue resolved. Thanks Alot.. I used version "0.5.0-rc.1" with features = { [ "json"]} and it worked.